# Cloud functions for firebase finished with status: 'timeout'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Function gets executed without errors. I am getting the status

> Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

I am not sure what the issue is. Everything in my function looks good to me. I also noticed functions sometimes take several seconds to update database and sometimes it is instantly. Is it normal that execution times varies from instantly to couple second? Should execution times be instantly?

```
exports.countproposals = functions.database.ref("/proposals/{jobid}/{propid}").onWrite((event) => {
    const jobid = event.params.jobid;
    const userId = event.params.propid;
    const userRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/proposals/sent`);
    if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
        userRef.child(jobid).set({
            timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        });
    } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
        userRef.child(jobid).remove();
    }
    const collectionRef = admin.database().ref(`/jobs/${jobid}`);
    const countRef = collectionRef.child("proposals");
    return countRef.transaction(current => {
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) + 1;
        } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) - 1;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that Cloud Functions for Firebase is in beta right now.  The team is still ironing out some of the rough edges.  When the product exits beta, there should be a better guarantees about performance.

Comment: same here, in addition to that it seems that the function is starting again.. like in an infinite loop, my logs are stacking up (im my case there is an error)

Comment: were u running this with live or local emulator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my experience I would guess that this is (hopefully) a temporary problem with firebase function itself. 
I get the same warnings/error for a function which yesterday took ~200 milliseconds to execute in average.